# How do you select options in a dropdown using capybara?

Tags: ruby, xpath, css-selectors, capybara

I am trying to use capybara to target a value within a dropdown menu that lives within an iframe. Here is the HTML for the dropdown that I am trying to select:

```
<select class="colored required" aria-required="true" id="birthdate-month" name="birthdate-month" aria-label="Birth Month">
      <option value="">Month</option>
      <option value="01">January</option>
      <option value="02">February</option>
      <option value="03">March</option>
      <option value="04">April</option>
      <option value="05">May</option>
      <option value="06">June</option>
      <option value="07">July</option>
      <option value="08">August</option>
      <option value="09">September</option>
      <option value="10">October</option>
      <option value="11">November</option>
      <option value="12">December</option>
</select>
```

Here is the step definition I have written to try and target that dropdown menu and select an option within it:

```
find('#birthdate-month').find(:xpath, 'option[06]').select_option
```

When I run this, I get:

> 'Unable to find css "#birthdate-month" (Capybara::ElementNotFound)'.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

EDIT:
I got it to work by inserting this into my step definition

```
browser = page.driver.browser
browser.switch_to.frame(iframe_name)
step(step)
browser.switch_to.default_content
```

Comment: the select is visible?

Comment: how would i check if it is visible?

Comment: Does Capybara even take that into account? Normally a selector doesn't care if an element is visible or not, so long as it is in the DOM.

Comment: I'm not seeing an issue with the CSS selector, but the `option[06]` XPath doesn't look right... what if you tried `'option[@value='06']` instead?

Comment: @BoltClock You may be right, but right now it's not even getting to that point because I can't even get it to find the element that containing that xpath. I can tinker with the xpath later once I can get it to find the CSS element, I think.

Comment: Not sure if this matters, but this dropdown I am trying to target lives within an iframe. Could that be why capybara isn't able to find it?